# [React Native][0.71] Plugin with id 'com.facebook.react' not found

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle

Plugin with id 'com.facebook.react' not found.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'android/app/build.gradle' line: 2
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Plugin with id 'com.facebook.react' not found.

```
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'android/app/build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Plugin with id 'com.facebook.react' not found.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Answer (score 8):

## Solution

Add `classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")` in `android/build.gradle` dependencies

[image]

Comment: this doesn't work

Comment: Only doing this did not fix my error. I got passed this error by:
-Updating API target in the gradle 
-Clearing the cache files in android studio

Comment: please be more specific on how you passed this issue

Comment: This worked for me, so it is situational!

Comment: Did not work for me

Answer (score 2):

I found [this docs page](https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/integration-with-existing-apps#configuring-gradle) useful for this specific issue, but it just led to a new issue... The root of my more general issue was that I was upgrading from a lower version of React Native, and had forgotten to include some of the changes needed. The best way to fix these kinds of issues is to use the [React Native Upgrade Helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/), which will show you exactly what needs to change using a sample application.

Comment: @1346778 thx for the hint, your solution seems to be the more orthodox.
Now that I'm checking version diff I'm supposed to update the files manually? 
Lots of diffs show are not there in real code and it seems something prone to error.
There is no CLI or other tool to do this automatically?